# Find out recursive depth of calls to 'cmd' within command prompt

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

I basically want to run the `cmd` command within the basic command prompt of Windows indefinitely. How would one be able to figure out the recursive depth of this?

I tried it manually a couple times, it seems the limit is quite high...
Trying `cmd & cmd & cmd ...` would only open the command prompt after the previous one was closed.
I also tried `cmd | cmd | cmd ...` which would do some weird stuff.

How can one recursively call cmd to find out when the recursive depth is reached?

Comment: I imagine it would depend on the size of your process table, which depends on the system you're running. Each instance of cmd is it's own process. Once the process table is full you can't start any new processes.

Comment: Aha, I have inspected the task manager and found a ton of cmd processes. Where can one find how big the process table is, or else, calculate/determine how big it is?

Comment: @emsimpson92 - This is on Microsoft Windows, not on Linux.

Comment: Command prompt... yeah got it. Slow morning lol.

Comment: I suppose you could always write a quick batch script that recursively runs cmd until you fill your table, and then just inspect the process count with task manager

Comment: I am sure the system would slow down to a state in which being able to run task manager becomes somewhat impossible.

Comment: In windows there is not a hard limit on how many processes you can start, but any process needs memory, so, you are simply limited by the available memory.

Comment: @MCND I accept that as an answer. Because stackframes are built on top of each other, this means your stack will be growing out to infinity basically, which is the limiting factor then.

Comment: Mark Russinovich (primary author of SysInternalsSuite) has written an article related to this question. The `testlimit.exe` and `testlimit64.exe` will probably be of interest. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/07/05/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/